# Dynamically create variables of a object

Tags: javascript, json

I am taking a json file and reorganizing it as a object in a new format (Not the same formatting as the json file I am reading, as I want to group variables differently) so I can use it. This requires creating a lot of variables with names that are unknown in advance.

I can dynamically create a new variable in my project like this:

```
object[variablename]
```

However, I would like to be able to do things like this

```
library[musicLibrary.Key].name = musicLibrary.alblum;
```

and

```
library[musicLibrary.Key].songs.[musicLibrary.title].name = musicLibrary.song;
```

Is there any way I can possibly do this?

My current looping code for the json looks like this:

```
var library = {}; 

for(var i = 0; i < musicList.songs.length; i++) {
//read json and reorganise it into a object
}
```

Comment: you can try use [JSON.parse with reviver function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) what json you try parse?

Comment: `library[musicLibrary.Key].name` should be valid syntax...maybe you just need to add `library[musicLibrary.Key]={}` first?

Comment: JSON are you Arrays by Key
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object

Comment: @Grundy I have seen that but it won't work for me becuase I am changing up the json file when I convert it into a object, It's not quite the same as the original json file.

Comment: @Passerby Thanks! That worked. And advice for my second piece?

Comment: @joshua-anderson The same: add `if(!("songs" in library[musicLibrary.Key])){library[musicLibrary.Key].songs={musicLibrary.title:{}};}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(var i = 0; i < musicList.songs.length; i++) {
    var key = musicLibrary.Key;
    library[key] = library[key] || {};
    library[key]['name'] = musicLibrary.alblum;
    library[key]['songs'] = library[key]['songs'] || {};
    library[key]['songs'][musicLibrary.title] = library[key]['songs'][musicLibrary.title]  || {};
    library[key]['songs'][musicLibrary.title]['name'] = musicLibrary.song;
}
```